# How can I use offset, or something like it, to move a cell value over and then up to the first cell that is a specific color?

Tags: vba

I have not done anything like this in a spreadsheet so could use some help.  I am finding a cell in a column that is colored a certain color then moving that value over to the right and need to move it up to the next cell that is another color.  I am not sure if I can use a version of offset.  Here is what I am working with.

```
    For Each cell In Range("R1:R150000")
       If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
      cell.Offset(0, 2).
```

But I am not sure how to get it to go up until it finds a yellow cell and place the value there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim cell As Range, c2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("R1:R150000").Cells
        'remember the last yellow cell two columns to the right
        With cell.Offset(0, 2)
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then Set c2 = .Cells(1)
        End With
        
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            If Not c2 Is Nothing Then 'have a yellow cell to copy to?
                c2.Value = cell.Value
                Set c2 = Nothing      'clear this cell so we don't overwrite it later...
            Else
                MsgBox "No destination cell available for " & cell.Address
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This works awesome, but if there are more than one cells of that color I need to add the two values to each other when putting them in the new cell.  It is only grabbing the first one of that color and skipping the next one.  I need to grab all the cells of color 4 and add them together in the new cell until the loop hits the next yellow then start over.  Any ideas?  thanks for all the help.  I am not a great vba guy but I muddle through.

Comment: "add them together" means sum them, or list all the values in the cell?

Comment: You can remove the `Set c2 = Nothing` and change `c2.Value = cell.Value` to `c2.Value = c2.Value + cell.Value` or `c2.Value = c2.Value & " " & cell.Value` depending on how you want to combine the values.